# How to Create Many to Many Relationship in Backand

Tags: backand

My DB has Items and Categories. Each Item will have several Categories.

I can create an object and a collection however when added my object(ITEM) I can only add one variable to the collection(Category).

I need Many to Many Relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The many to many in Backand done by adding an object that has relationships to each object, you can view it all here: [many-to-many](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/getting_started/objects/#many-to-many-relationship)

You can also review the codepen.io to see how to work with many to many and Angular.

Many to many model between users and pets looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "pets",
    "fields": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "owners": {
      "collection": "users-pets",
      "via": "pet"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "users-pets",
  "fields": {
    "pet": {
      "object": "pets"
    },
    "owner": {
      "object": "users"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "users",
  "fields": {
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "pets": {
      "collection": "users-pets",
      "via": "owner"
     }
   }
 }
]
```